# SDL Audio vs PortAudio

Tags: sdl, portaudio

I am searching for an opensource, cross-platform and free (for commercial usage) audio input/output library. Search finally boiled down to SDL(1.3) and PortAudio. SDL supports large number of platforms and sound systems. But it is not very well optimized and it is difficult to extend any functionality which may be required at later stages. Whereas portaudio has everything which I need. Your opinions on using audio input/output libraries would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered it yourself :

> portaudio has everything which I need

and

> SDL supports large number of platforms
>   and sound systems. But it is **not very
>   well optimized and it is difficult to
>   extend any functionality which may be
>   required at later stages**.

Why look any further?